# beautifulsoup, Find th with text 'price', then get price from next th

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My html looks like:

```
<td>
   <table ..>
      <tr>
         <th ..>price</th>
         <th>$99.99</th>
      </tr>
   </table>
</td>
```

So I am in the current table cell, how would I get the 99.99 value?

I have so far:

```
td[3].findChild('th')
```

But I need to do:

**Find th with text 'price', then get next th tag's string value.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think about it in "steps"... given that some `x` is the root of the subtree you're considering,

```
x.findAll(text='price')
```

is the list of all items in that subtree containing text `'price'`.  The parents of those items then of course will be:

```
[t.parent for t in x.findAll(text='price')]
```

and if you only want to keep those whose "name" (tag) is `'th'`, then of course

```
[t.parent for t in x.findAll(text='price') if t.parent.name=='th']
```

and you want the "next siblings" of those (but only if they're also `'th'`s), so

```
[t.parent.nextSibling for t in x.findAll(text='price')
 if t.parent.name=='th' and t.parent.nextSibling and t.parent.nextSibling.name=='th']
```

Here you see the problem with using a list comprehension: too much repetition, since we can't assign intermediate results to simple names.  Let's therefore switch to a good old loop...:

**Edit**: added tolerance for a string of text between the parent `th` and the "next sibling" as well as tolerance for the latter being a `td` instead, per OP's comment.

```
for t in x.findAll(text='price'):
  p = t.parent
  if p.name != 'th': continue
  ns = p.nextSibling
  if ns and not ns.name: ns = ns.nextSibling
  if not ns or ns.name not in ('td', 'th'): continue
  print ns.string
```

I've added `ns.string`, that will give the next sibling's contents if and only if they're just text (no further nested tags) -- of course you can instead analize further at this point, depends on your application's needs!-).  Similarly, I imagine you won't be doing just `print` but something smarter, but I'm giving you the structure.

Talking about the structure, notice that twice I use `if...: continue`: this reduces nesting compared to the alternative of inverting the `if`'s condition and indenting all the following statements in the loop -- and "flat is better than nested" is one of the koans in the Zen of Python (`import this` at an interactive prompt to see them all and meditate;-).

Comment: great answer alex, I have just been using findAll so far and now I feel I can traverse the dom with this knowledge, go python! hehe

Comment: in the link 'if not ns or ns.name...', if ns is None then ns.name will fail no?

Comment: actually my HTML is like:  <th>price</th><td>$99.99</td> and p.nextSibling is empty, I tried p.next and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Blackman, `or` _short-circuits_, so in `not ns or ns.name` the `ns.name` will not evaluate if `ns` is false -- so, to your first comment, nope, you don't need to worry.

Comment: @Blackman, wrt your second comment, see my edit -- one extra line of code to optionally skip some text between the parent `th` and the "next" (which then isn't "next"!-) sibling, and an altered check to accept either `th` or `td` as the tag we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With pyparsing, it's easy to reach into the middle of some HTML for a tag pattern like this:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, Combine, Word, nums

th,thEnd = makeHTMLTags("TH")
floatnum = Combine(Word(nums) + "." + Word(nums))
priceEntry = (th + "price" + thEnd + 
              th + "$" + floatnum("price") + thEnd)

tokens,startloc,endloc = priceEntry.scanString(html).next()

print tokens.price
```

Pyparsing's `makeHTMLTags` helper returns a pair of pyparsing expressions, one for the start tag and one for the end tag.  The start tag pattern is much more than just adding "<>"s around the given string, but also allows for extra whitespace, variable case, and the presence or absence of tag attributes.  For instance, note that even though I specified "TH" as the table head tag, it will also match "th", "Th", "tH" and "TH".  Pyparsing's default whitespace skipping behavior will also handle extra spaces, between tag and "$", between "$" and numeric price, etc., without having to sprinkle "zero or more whitespace chars could go here" indicators.  Lastly, by assigning the results name "price" (following `floatum` in the definition of `priceEntry`), it makes it very simple to access that specific value from the full list of tokens matching the overall `priceEntry` expression.

(Combine is used for 2 purposes: it disallows whitespace between the components of the number; and returns a single combined token "99.99" instead of the list `["99", ".", "99"]`.)